# Metta and Loving-Kindness as a Team

Tags: meditation-metta, loving-kindness

Can Metta be practiced in a partnership or as a team?

I can think of

- two people practicing Metta together, or
- a group which meets for meditation, or
- across borders, across continents people meditate together at a certain time.

Are there any indications of a Sutta?

Are there practices of a tradition?

Comment: Hi Lou and welcome to Buddhism SE. We have a [Guide](http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/1502/i-am-a-new-user-here-at-buddhism-se-what-should-i-know-before-i-post?cb=1) and a [Resource tab](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help) for new users that you might like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meditation influences the surrounding by vibration created. (You can really feel the vibration when you experience [Piti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C4%ABti)) So when you pratice as a group these vibrations influence others, especially when you are having a bad patch in meditation then the influence of others will help in to develop calmness and concentration and perhaps dispel agitation and other hindrances that might have surfaced during your worldly interactions.

This is true for all types of meditation but most effective when doing Metta as vibrations tend to be stronger.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a mentioning, the famous sutta, its starts out with hints of being withdrawn from the world like "not overly attached to families" and is actually not meant as a social event. But since "sex" sells it is broadly sold like that, introduced like that. If one just likes to maintain pleasant feeling, one can go on an thinks this way, but if one has certain metta (maybe for the living beings that would lose there lives to be able to meet in a beloved group) and like to put his practice also in line with metta, this first lines of the Suttas become to have reasons.

There is a nice summary of all qualities required to practice metta and its really not an ordinary mans task and so is it with the benefits one would gain, of which you would just gain sort time pleasure if its made for simply some personal pleasure.

[Karaṇīya Metta-Sutta - The Message of Peace and Universal Friendliness](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/an/an03/an03.099.than_en.html), by Ven. Ñāṇadassana Maha Thera.

And to your question if there are such metta-events and practices, actually 95% are of such as you have thought of.

One might also consider the question and answer here in: [Metta and Loving-Kindness as a Team](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/questions/13154/metta-and-loving-kindness-as-a-team)

See also: [Metta Means Goodwill](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/authors/nanadassana/metta_en.html) (Thanissaro Bhikkhu). At least metta is not meant to get involved, but more a beneficial kind of thought for others for one who is actually on leave or on a journey, leaving for a good with the thought "*Sabbe sattā sukhī attānaṃ pariharantu.*" "May all living beings look after themselves with ease." ([The Sublime Attitudes](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/lib/authors/dhammayut/chanting_en.html#sublime) | [audio](http://sangham.net/index.php?action=tpmod;dl=get197))

So where do you like to go?

*(Note: this answer has not been given with the agreement to be means of trade or the purpose of/for trade and/or keep people trapped and bound. How you handle it lies in your sphere, but does not excuse the deed here either.)*

Answer (score 1):

You are allowed to practice as a team. In fact in Lord Buddha's time and even now people and Monks do it. But the important thing is to use this good friendship as a boat and use the excitement of teamwork to your benefit.

Remember not to be too attached to the team. You will be more willing to meditate when yo got friends around.

Even Lord Buddha said

> Good friends (Kalyana mitta) are the strength of Buddhism

But never discuss your meditation with your friends, Because it will awake each others ego and that would do more harm than good. But if you have any issues with your practice seek the help of a good master. I would advice you to seek a kind monk because ordinary people can be a bit ego driven.

Comment: "*In fact in Lord Buddha's time* and even now people and Monks do it." Yes?! and "Good friends (Kalyana mitta) are the strength of Buddhism" <-> "But never discuss your meditation with your friends" Yes?! So one seeks out for friend, to remember that they are no friends and then meditates with them and try to be exited in hope for a unordinary person to say "you have to walk alone"? or how should it be understood?

Comment: One must seek out friends when that person is new and need extra push towards dhamma because it is easy to loose the way and return to the common life. This method is approved by Lord Buddha and when they have matured enough they can walk alone. Like a child a new comer to Buddhism need the help of good friends. And friendship do not necessarily mean attachment. After all even arahants used to gather and chant or discuss dhamma even though there is not reason to do it as they all have achieved Nirvana. They did this because good company is always nice and comforting to a Buddhist @SamanaJohann

Comment: "They did..." Is mr/mrs Theravada sure?  "...this because good company is always nice and comforting to a Buddhist.." and what about this? and that an Arahat might be maybe not a Buddhist, even does not seeks for freinds? *"One must seek out friends when that person is new and need extra push towards dhamma because it is easy to loose the way and return to the common life."*, is quite a good advice, to be advised. Isn't it that there are two main tasks? Discussing the or dwell in silence (e.g. 2 Jhana+)

Comment: Yes they did, As you may have heard many teachings exist that has nothing to do with a dialog of lord Buddha but a dialog between Two Arahats. These dialogs play out as if they are teaching each other but they have already realized these things. I learned from a monk that these dialogs played out as the outcome of a custom That arahats had, a custom to re-memorize or chant,discuss dhamma so that they feel the depth of the path which was some sort of a commonly respected thing among arahats which also provided much needed elaboration to deep teachings to ones who listened. @SamanaJohann

Comment: If you seek you will find some good deep conversations from great Kashyapa arahant who was considered "Dhamma senadhipathi" (General of Buddhist teaching). @SamanaJohann

Comment: As you already know Lord Buddha directly said "No being can reach nirvana or goals in nirvana without being a follower of the path taught by Lord Buddhas". An arahat who is not a Buddhist is not possible, As lord Buddha explained there is a value only Lord Buddha's hold which is called "Samma sambuddha" which means "Ralized the path without the help of a teaching or a teacher". So the most major difference between an arahat and a Lord Buddha is that an arahat had the help of the teaching to reach nirvana and Lord Buddhas did not. @SamanaJohann

Comment: It is possible that an arahat would not choose friends and stay in isolation but it is not possible an arahat not being a Buddhist. This is not my saying it is Lord Buddha's saying, refer the "Sutta/Sutra pitaka" in theravada to learn more. The only way to have a person become an arahat without previously being a Buddhist is if that person was a Bodhisattva who started the path in his last life. And with him being an arahat he would also reach the status of a Lord Buddha or the other kind of Buddha's who do not build followers (Pase Buddha). @SamanaJohann

Comment: What does Theravada think? Is wanting to be something or somebody a reason for suffering quarrel and stress? Is being something and not loosing it a reason for suffering quarrel and stress? Does somebodies destiny depend on what he/she is, depending on his definition on his birth? Is defining one self with a group the reason of suffering quarrel and stress? Would there be quarrel and suffering, if people would not misunderstood?

Comment: @SamanaJohann Now i am answering these questions in the Abhidhamma point of view,not in a day to day standpoint.  Wanting to be somebody is not forbidden to a buddhist,but this is essentially a product of the illusion that normal beings have called "Sakkhaya ditti" (The misunderstanding that people have that there is a soul or a person).  But if we look at the question will trying to be someone become a source of suffering, the answer is yes. Not just in normal lie even in a Monks life this exist. This suffering exist because of not yet reachng the goal in mind and it will continue to exist...

Comment: ...Until the goal is met. This suffering exist even in the path towards Nirvana. Lord Buddha clearly stated that. And the simple answer is, Yes wanting to be someone is accepted and allowed in Buddhism but who ever   is trying to do that will face some stress and suffering which is temporary. This uncomfortableness will disappear when the goal is met. @SamanaJohann

Comment: @SamanaJohann , As Lord Buddha said everything is temporary and who ever alive is also the same. So if someone has something that thing is going to go away eventually. Let's say i got a car and it does run very well, and lets think it worked forever. Now there is nothing wrong with the car and it works well until eternity. But i will still loose it when i die. So there is nothing that does not loose from a being. So there is no way someone will feel bad for not loosing something because everything goes away one day. And the only thing that does not go away is Nirvana and the goals of the path.

Comment: @SamanaJohann , As Buddhists we do not believe in destiny. What we believe is "Karma". So what you said is exactly the other way around. Karma defines a persons appearance,skills,intelligence,wisdom and etc. So Karma is always a dominant factor. But as Lord Buddha said Karma alone does not define everything, your choices do effect as much. Karma will define the Birth,gender,cast,environment,Body and etc. But unless very powerful Karma exist a person can change a lot by his or her will and choices.

Comment: @SamanaJohann , Being in a group or being alone is not the reason of suffering. But Having to part from the ones a person like or having to be with people a person does not like will cause suffering. The reason for suffering as to Lord Buddha is "Aviddhya" (Not realizing). What a person should do to part from pain or suffering is to learn and realize dhamma (the teaching). Until then where a person is will not matter because the issue is within the person not outside.

Comment: @SamanaJohann , Other people matter to normal ones like us because it is going to affect our ego. But other really do not matter because no one can truly convince all the people. As you might have learned even lord Buddha had people who wanted to take revenge from triple gems. There has never been a world without misunderstanding. And it does not matter either because pain like any other emotion is born in our own heads. The reason it occur is that we have given it grounds to grow. We feed all our emotions and therefore we are responsible for what we feel,not the outside world.

Comment: It not good to think in terms of we, Upasaka Theravada. Its modern and many people use it for concernment. Buddha Dhamma is a medicine to heal individualism and use it as a group medicine causes even more attachment and suffering. When one grows more independent and had developed metta for this one is able to help. Its not good to make something dear. [Dear Ones](http://zugangzureinsicht.org/html/tipitaka/kn/dhp/dhp.16.than_en.html), remember the metta sutta "not attached to families". It needs a lot of real metta to walk the way for the benefit of all.

Comment: True bhante, what i wanted to say to this OP was that if someone needs help he can get it even though isolation can benefit him. What i was thinking was that a saying from my teacher, he said "The path has not changed but the people have and that's why we do not have great ones among us like the old days who reached nirvana and other goals, The way i see it it is a matter of will/conviction that people seems to lack. In the age of Lord Buddha people were with very strong will and they reached heights because of that, but today people have shraddha but not the will to keep pushing...."

Comment: ...and because of that i think it is better if you can find good friends who would encourage you more into the path as everyone and everything else is already there to push you away".   This is what my teacher said and i honestly think it is true. What do you think? @SamanaJohann